# Warning: ssh2_connect(): Failed overriding server to client COMP method

Tags: php, ssh, compression

I have a problem with enabling compression for SSH session in PHP.

Part of code:

```
    $methods = array(
    'server_to_client' => array(
        'comp' => 'zlib')
    );if(!($con = ssh2_connect("10.214.201.31", 22, $methods))){
    ...
```

Warning during execution (via httpd or php cli):

```
Warning: ssh2_connect(): Failed overriding server to client COMP method
```

Compression doesn't work (time of downloading test file via ssh2_scp_recv didn't change). Similar warning after setup client to server compression.

```
PHP Version 5.5.15 (latest Xampp for Windows)
ZLib Version    1.2.7
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.3
```

Server support ssh compression (WinSCP download 5x faster).

Can't find any additional information in logs for php or httpd.

How should I investigate this issue?

Comment: Can you use Putty to SSH to the server (to prove the credential is working)? Make sure you choose "Enable Compression" in Putty

Comment: Yes, login/pass is good, this code works good (but download is too slow), so I'm trying to add compression and save some execution time.

Comment: Can you post the PuTTY logs? Just because the "Enable Compression" checkbox is checked doesn't necessarily mean compression *is* being used. You can get the Putty logs by enabling logging. To do so go PuTTY->Session->Logging and checking the "SSH packets" radio button.

Comment: I didn't use putty for verification. I verified with WinSCP and 100Mb text (log) file download via slow VPN. After compression enabling download was 5x faster.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the version of libssh php5 was compiled with. Tried this on my desktop, and ran into the same issue.

```
> ssh -C -vv root@host.com
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 zlib@openssh.com
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 zlib@openssh.com
```

You can see that my client supports compression methods `zlib@openssh.com`, `zlib`, and `none` while the server only supports `zlib@openssh.com` and `none`, so the key exchange process eventually settles on using `zlib@openssh.com`.

Unfortunately, support for compression type `zlib@openssh.com` [wasn't added to libssh2 until **1.4.3**](http://www.libssh2.org/changes.html) and yup, you guessed it, my php5.4 was compiled with libssh **1.2.7**.

```
> phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
....
ssh2

SSH2 support => enabled
extension version => 0.11.3-dev
libssh2 version => 1.2.7
banner => SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.2.7
remote forwarding => enabled
hostbased auth => enabled
polling support => enabled
publickey subsystem => enabled
```

**TL;DR**: If WinSCP is using `zlib@openssh.com` as the compression, make sure your php is compiled against at libssh2 1.4.3.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I use latest php with libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.3. In case of WinSCP or Putty connection (with compression) Wireshark shows `none,zlib@openssh.com` as compression in "Key Exchange Init" message from server and `zlib,none` in message/reply from client. In case of php ssh2 connection Wiresharkk shows same "Key Exchange Init" message from server and only `none` as compression in message/reply from client. So I think `@openssh.com` shouldn't be meaningfull in compression estalishment.